# Adding photos to blog comments using paperclip (nesting models?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am just beginning in rails and I think that my question has to do with nesting models, but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Basically, I am trying to create a blog with user created posts. As a typical blog works, within each post I want to add the functionality of adding comments. Now the images come in to play on two levels: 1) I want the users to be able to create Posts and on the post they will upload an image. Now once that post is created, I want the commenters to be able to add comments and upload different images on the respective post page.

I have created the blog model with posts and comments, no problem. I have also added paperclip and created the functionality to add the 'upload an image' option to both the posts and comments. But I've only been able to get the post images to appear on the show page (which is a feed of all the current posts) and the individual post pages themselves. I try to add images to comments and for some reason I am getting an incorrect path, which results in either "Missing_small" or an incorrect path message.

**Post Model**

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

      validates :name,  :presence => true
      validates :title, :presence => true,
                        :length => { :minimum => 5 }

      has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments


     # Paperclip

      has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "150x150>", :large => "360x360" },
                        :url => "/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style_:basename.:extension",
                        :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style_:basename.:extension"

      validates_attachment_presence :photo
      validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
      validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
    end
```

**Comment Model**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :photo_file_name, :photo_file_size, :photo_content_type

  belongs_to :post

  # Paperclip

    has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "150x150>", :large => "360x360" },
                      :url => "/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style_:basename.:extension",
                      :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style_:basename.:extension",
                      :default_url => '/images/missing_:style.png'


    validates_attachment_presence :photo
    validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
    validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
end
```

**Posts Show View**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
 <% if @post.photo? %>
   <%= image_tag @post.photo.url(:small) %>
 <% else %>
   No attachment available!
 <% end %>
</p>
<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @post.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Content:</b>
  <%= @post.content %>
</p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
 <%= render @post.comments %>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render "comments/form" %>

<br />

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %> |
```

**Comment View**

```
<p>
 <%= image_tag comment.photo.url(:small) %>
</p>
<p>
 <b>Commenter:</b>
 <%= comment.commenter %>
</p>

<p>
 <b>Comment:</b>
 <%= comment.body %>
</p>

<p>
 <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.post, comment],
                  :confirm => "Are you sure?",
                 :method => :delete %>
</p>
```

Let me know if you need anything else to help me.

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the commenters to be able to
>   add comments and upload different
>   images on the respective post page

I am not completly clear on whether you want to be able to upload multiple images for a single Post or Comment.

To give you that option, i would create a Photo model, and it's this which has the paperclip association.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_attached_file :data  
end
```

And then the question is how does this photo belong to both a comment and a post? for that you can use polymorphic associations.

This [tutorial](http://shiningthrough.co.uk/Dynamic-multiple-image-uploads-with-Ruby-on-Rails) kind of does what you want (replace Product with Post) but you will have to extend it with polymorphic associations so it works with both Comments and Posts.

Comment: Jon - to be more clear, I want each post to have the originally uploaded image, but within that post, each comment will only have 1 image per comment. To recap: the original post has 1 image and nested below that, the comments which have 1 photo per comment. I'm gonna give this a shot and see how it goes. Thanks for the help, I'll let you know.